# Font-Family does not looks like how it should be

Tags: php, css, html

I have been trying to put my font-family to Clarendon Lt BT Light, but it has been reflecting New Times Roman to me.

This wasn't an issue to me until now.

I placed this at the top of my CSS file.:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ClarendonLtBtLight';
    src: url(../fonts/ClarendonLtBtLight.ttf);
}
```

This is how I apply it to my webpage:

```
nav.main_menu > ul > li > a {
    color: #686868;             
    font-family: 'ClarendonLtBtLight';    
    font-size: 18px;      
    font-style: normal;      
    font-weight: 600;      
    text-transform: uppercase;       
    letter-spacing: 1px;     
 }
```

I had also place the .tff place to the correct directory.

Please advice.

Comment: This is not a WordPress issue.

Comment: Hi @Florian, I am aware that this is not the issue on Wordpress, but Web Development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a reference error. Try opening the developer console on your browser as you load the page. See if you can find errors such as: "NOT FOUND", etc.

Comment: Hi @Earlee, thank you for your reply. Yes, it does show that. I am looking back into the directory again.